# Oracle SQL subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

Display employee `last_name`, `salary` and `job` who work either in `IT` or `MARKETING` department and earn more than the worst paid person in the `ACCOUNTING`  department. Sort the output by the last name alphabetically.

My answer:

```
select 
    last_name, salary, job_id 
from 
    employees 
where 
    salary > (select min(salary) 
              from employees 
              where department_id = (select department id 
                                     from departments 
                                     where department_name like'IT' 
                                        or like 'Marketing'));
```

Comment: sample table? db details and version?  Please try creating the tables in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want, but it sounds something like this. Add other columns in select query as you want.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfb31c/5/0

```
select e.last_name,e.salary,e.department_id from
employee e inner join department d
on e.department_id=d.department_id
where d.department_name in ('IT','MARKETING')
and e.salary > (select min(e1.salary) from employee e1
                inner join department d1
                where e1.department_id=d1.department_id
                and d1.department_name = 'ACCOUNTING')
order by e.last_name
```

**Update**

Same statement, reformatted.
Also removed `inner` keyword and fixed `on` clause, so SQL is vendor neutral, i.e. works on MySQL, MS SQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, ...

```
select e.last_name, e.salary, e.department_id
  from employee e
  join department d on d.department_id = e.department_id
 where d.department_name in ('IT','MARKETING')
   and e.salary > ( select min(e1.salary)
                      from employee e1
                      join department d1 on d1.department_id = e1.department_id
                     where d1.department_name = 'ACCOUNTING' )
 order by e.last_name
```

Comment: It would appear that MySQL (your fiddle) is very lenient, because the second `inner join` has no `on` clause. The formatting of the statement could also use some work.

Comment: `on` clause is not needed as long as joining condition is mentioned in `where` clause. It is the same thing.

Comment: But yeah any inputs on further formatting will be good. I am always ready to learn.

Comment: Updated answer with better format. Also, the question has keyword `oracle`, and the `on` clause is **not** optional on Oracle and Microsoft, so fixed that too. FYI: It is optional for MySQL and PostgreSQL, but always including it makes the SQL vendor neutral.

Comment: Cool thanks. Yeah making a query SQL vendor neutral is a good point. Will keep that in mind.